# VueJs showing/rendering only one object at a time from a response of 100s of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My API gives me a response which is 100s of objects and at a time, I would like to show only one object displayed on a page, The page has 2 buttons like Previous and Next that can goto previous object or next object. I am getting all of this data(100s of object) in one http response. How do i handle this. What is the vue way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fetching all the items at once, you could have a `currentItemIndex` data field that you increment/decrement to navigate between them and a `currentItem` computed field that fetches the corresponding item from the list that you can then use in your template.

If you have a *lot* of objects you might want to consider server side paging.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the first approach you suggested please feel free to add any best practices links, resources or anything in comments.